# potential violation of law of excluded middle

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-logic

Consider the following sentence:

"Either Santa Claus is hungry or Santa Claus is not hungry."

This seems to be a straightforward application of the law of excluded middle. However, it also seems like both disjuncts could be seen as problematic. Santa Claus has to exist to be hungry, but Santa Claus doesn't exist by stipulation, so that disjunct can't be correct. And if similar reasoning applies to his being not hungry, then we would have a situation where the LEM sanctioned a false disjunction. So what's going on here? Do we need to modify our commitment to the LEM? Or is there some reason that it actually isn't violated in this case?

Comment: Options: convert into a hypothetical: "If Santa Claus exists, he is either hungry or not hungry." (Then say, "If Santa Claus does not exist, then he is not hungry, as he satisfies no descriptions, as such, at all, in the first place.") Or: "According to the story of Christmas, Santa Claus is either hungry or not hungry."

Comment: In first-order logic you would have to write "Santa Claus is hungry" as something like "there exists an x such that SantaClaus(x) and hungry(x)", and the negation of that would be "there does not exist an x such that SantaClaus(x) and hungry(x)", which is in fact true if there is no x satisfying SantaClaus(x). So if you stick the the formalism of first-order logic, this would not be an exception to the rule that anytime you pair a proposition with its own negation, one must be true and the other false.

Comment: If Santa Claus is not in the domain of discourse then it is a non-referring term, and in standard logic expressions with non-referring terms are not well-formed expressions. So LEM does not sanction anything involving them. But existing "in reality" is not a precondition for being in the domain of discourse, we routinely include fictional entities into such domains. If Santa Claus is there then LEM applies and the disjunction is true. Alternatively, you can paraphrase "Santa Clause" into a definite description, as Hypnosifl suggested, and LEM will still apply, but the negation is different.

Comment: On dealing with non-referring terms systematically without fictionalizing the domain of discourse, see [SEP, Free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/), which extends the standard logic to them.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the existence of Santa Claus and the excluded middle, Bertrand Russell dealt with puzzles like these in his paper 'On Denoting'.

The classic example is 'The King of France is bald' and 'The King of France is not bald'. Russell distinguishes two scopes in which it can be read, **narrow** and **wide***.

For example, Russell identifies a sentence 'I thought your yacht was larger than it is' as to have:

**A narrow scope reading:**

- I thought the size of your yacht is bigger than the size of your yacht.

**A wide scope reading:**

- There is a size x, such that the size of your yacht is x, and I
  thought that the size of your yacht is bigger than x.

So, the proposition:

- Either Santa Claus is hungry, or Santa Claus is not hungry.

Expresses truth only if two disjuncts contradict each other. The left disjunct is obviously false, but the right one has two possible readings:

**1. A wide scope reading:**

- ∃x (Sx ∧ ∀y (Sy → y = x) ∧ ¬Hx)
- There is a unique x who is Santa Claus, and x is not hungry.

**2. A narrow scope reading:**

- ¬∃x (Sx ∧ ∀y (Sy → y = x) ∧ Hx)
- It is not the case that there is a unique x who is Santa Claus, and x is hungry.

If the scope is wide (**1.**), it is simply *false*. If the scope is narrow (**2.**), it is *true*. Only the **narrow** reading (**2.**) is the negation of the left disjunct, so the law of excluded middle is preserved.

(For further reading, I encourage engaging with the paper itself.)

*- A narrow scope is also called a **secondary occurrence**, and the wide scope is called a **primary occurrence**.

Answer (score 1):

In everyday language, “Santa Claus is hungry” means “Santa Claus exists, and Santa Claus is hungry”.  “Santa Claus is not hungry” means “Santa Claus exists, and Santa Claus is not hungry”. The correct negation of the first sentence is “Either Santa Claus doesn’t exist, or Santa Claus exists and is not hungry”.

So with the *correct* negation, there is no “excluded middle”. With the given, incorrect negation, there is the supply excluded “there is no Santa Claus”.

Answer (score 1):

"Either Santa Claus is hungry or Santa Claus is not hungry."

The following would be subject to the Law of the Excluded Middle: "Either it is the case that Santa Claus is hungry or it is not the case that Santa Claus is hungry." That is true because either Santa Claus exists and is hungry, or else either Santa Claus exists but is not hungry or Santa Claus does not exist and therefore is not hungry.

It's the meaning, not the structure of the sentence, that matters when applying the Law of the Excluded Middle. The English construction "Santa Claus is not hungry" is ambiguous: It can mean either "Santa Claus exists and is not hungry" or "Either Santa Claus exists and is not hungry or Santa Claus does not exist and therefore is not hungry." "Santa Claus is not hungry" must be construed the second way in order for the Law of the Excluded Middle to apply to "Either Santa Claus is hungry or Santa Claus is not hungry." Construing it the first way is what gives an apparent (but not real) violation of the Law of the Excluded Middle. It's unreal because on that first construal, the entire sentence does not have the form . Only on the second construal does the entire sentence have the form .

As I'm sure someone has noted, the classic example is "Either the king of France is bald or the king of France is not bald," at a time when there is no king of France. Here, too, the ambiguous phrasing of the second disjunct is the problem; so construing "the king of France is not bald" as not to allow for the possibility of the king's nonexistence is to construe the whole thing in a way that is not of the form . "Either the king of France is bald or it is not the case that the king of France is bald," which allows for the possibility that the king of France does not exist, has the form  and obeys the Law of the Excluded Middle perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

The model theory for classical FOL satisfies the formula ~H(s) if s is not in the extension of the predicate H, where H means “is hungry” and “s” refers to Santa Claus.

Further, we can distinguish between the truth of a formula in a model and what that formula is supposed to mean in real life. That is, if pushed to choose H(s) or ~H(s), I’d choose ~H(s) since it’s easy to create a model in which whatever “Santa Claus” actually refers to is not hungry. This is a bit of a stretch, but clearly we can speak of Santa meaningfully, else there’d be no worry in spoiling the truth that there is no Santa. The term ‘Santa Claus’ does mean a fat old man in a Red Suit, etc. but when we refer to ‘Santa Claus’ we refer to the idea/mythos behind him, and the way that those fictional things mingle with our real-world dealings with ‘Santa Claus’ in order to make sense of an object ‘Santa Claus’.

You can also do free logic, which does not allow for existential quantification unless it has been established that for a term t ∃x x=t. That is, the formula ∀x(H(x)∨~H(x)) is valid, but universal elimination on it is only valid for terms t that meet the requirement. So, we wouldn’t be able to derive a formula representing the proposition “Santa Claus is either hungry or not” without deriving that there is someone called Santa Claus.

Answer (score 0):

Logic has the concept of *well-formed* sentences. Before  being correct or incorrect, your sentence must be well formed, and yours wouldn't be.

Most valid logical formulas are based on *existential quantification* i.e. in order to say something about an object that don't exist by axiom, you have to say "There exists an object X such that object X is Santa Claus and object X is hungry."

Answer (score -1):

The common sense solution adopted by Gottlob Frege was that a sentence whose subject does not exist does not have a truth value, with the consequence that it is not a proposition and is therefore outside the scope of the law of excluded middle. Problem solved.

The solution proposed by Bertrand Russell in his paper On denoting published in 1905 requires to assume that the sentence "Santa Claus is hungry" says that Santa Claus exists, but this is clearly false, on the face of the sentence itself.

Comment: Do you at least agree with Russell that "Santa Claus is hungry" would be false if Santa Claus doesn't exist (and never did and never will), even if you disagree with his rationale?

Comment: @Hypnosifl I'm sure you don't believe in Santa Claus so it should be easy for you just to think about "Santa Claus is hungry". Still, If it was false, then its negation would have to be true, but, linguistic fact, its negation is "Santa Claus is not hungry", but according to Russell, it is also false. It just doesn't work, unless you want to believe in Russell's idea that "Santa Claus is hungry" says "Santa Claus exists and Santa Claus is hungry", which is as fantastic as the idea that Santa Claus exists. You don't believe in Santa Claus, but you still believe in Russell's Santa Claus theory.

Comment: There's no single notion of "linguistic negation", "It's not the case that Santa Claus is hungry" could also be seen as a linguistic negation of "Santa Claus is hungry". If you translate "Santa Claus is hungry" into 1st order logic and take its negation, the former ordinary-language statement would be a better translation. Are you arguing that "X is not hungry" is the *true* negation of "X is hungry" in terms of your belief that there's a unique "correct" version of logic rooted in biology? Can you point to animal behavior where they implicitly use this type of negation for nonexistent things?

Comment: @Hypnosifl 1. "*no single notion*" I didn't say there is only one form possible, but it is a linguistic fact that 99% of the time we use "X is not F" to negate "X is F". Russell produced a logical model of a non-existent language. 2. "*this type of negation for nonexistent things*" There is nothing special about the grammar of talking about non-existence things: "Your friend is an imaginary being" and "My friend is not an imaginary being". This is standard English. How come Russell doesn't speak standard English?

Comment: Why should logic reflect "standard English", which is highly context-dependent? For example, "Santa Claus is jolly" could be judged either true or false in English, depending on whether the speaker wanted to emphasize the defining characteristics of a fictional character, or to emphasize that Santa Claus doesn't exist. Logic is supposed to be about some abstract structure of assertions that allows us to judge certain inferences true or false without needing to know the meaning of adjectives or speaker's intentions. Do *you* judge "Santa Claus is jolly" to be definitely true or false logically?

Comment: Also, note that in standard English, it is often more common to use an contrary "positive" adjective to negate a sentence, rather than just adding "not"--for example, Aristotle at one point talked about how the contrary of "Socrates is sick" in ordinary language might sometimes be "Socrates is well" rather than "Socrates is not sick". But if we want to have a *logic* such that if Socrates doesn't exist, then "Socrates is sick" is automatically false and "Socrates is not sick" is automatically true, the logic needs a clear-cut distinction between positive and negative adjectives.

Comment: @Hypnosifl 1. "Socrates is well" This is a red herring. "Well" is understood as logically equivalent to "not sick". - 2. "logic needs a clear-cut distinction" No, not logic. We just need to decide what we mean by the words we use. So we just need to have a semantic for our language. - 3. "if Socrates doesn't exist" The existence of Socrates is irrelevant to logic. You really have bizarre ideas, all mathematical logic ideas.

Comment: As I said, the discussion of "Socrates is well" vs. "Socrates is not sick" comes directly from Aristotle's own writings. And Aristotle would agree with Bertrand Russell that the existence or non-existence of a thing *is* relevant to evaluating a statement about it--Aristotle specifically says that "Socrates is sick" is automatically false in the case that Socrates does not exist, just like Russell says "the golden mountain is golden" is false if a golden mountain does not exist.

Comment: (cont.) I asked you before, what do *you* think about propositions like "Santa Claus is jolly" that refer to entities that don't exist--do you think that statement is automatically false if Santa Claus doesn't exist (i.e. assuming a [domain of discourse](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/76995/why-is-the-notion-of-domain-of-discourse-at-all-necessary-in-predicate-logic) that does not include Santa Claus), or do you think it can be true?

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*Aristotle would agree*" Too bad for Aristotle 2. "*the existence or non-existence of a thing is relevant to evaluating a statement about it*" How do you verify that the king is or isn't bald when there is no king? Beats me. 3.  "*Santa Claus is jolly*" I already provided the answer: "*The common sense solution adopted by Gottlob Frege was that a sentence whose subject does not exist does not have a truth value,*"

Comment: OK, that's one solution you can adopt, but I wouldn't say it's more "common sense" than others since in natural language it's common to make definite assertions about fictional entities. I think most modern logicians would agree there are multiple possible sets of logical rules one can adopt and none represent some kind of One True Logic, your arguments always seem to presuppose such a One True Logic and that anyone using different rules is "wrong", but although you allude to evolutionary arguments you never show how your more specialized rules (like this one) are implicit in animal behavior.

Comment: @Hypnosifl Without One True Logic, no logical fundamental principle, and nothing to justifies mathematical theorems. The idea of One True Logic is as old as logic itself. Mathematical logic itself started out on this premise. Adoption of the material implication led some mathematicians to produce alternative models, which in turn led to the idea that there is no one true logic. Yet, either there is one true logic, or there is no logic at all. The idea of different logics falsifies the idea of logic. Why should anyone accept any mathematical theorem? - 2. "*animal behavior*" Human behaviour.

Comment: Just as there are multiple equivalent ways to build a universal Turing machine, why can't there be multiple logical frameworks that can all be used express some mathematical axiomatic system, such that a person using logic framework A and one using logic framework B won't disagree in any of their mathematical conclusions? I also would think that different logics can be equivalent in the sense that logic A (say, 1st order logic), supplied with the right axioms and predicates, could be used to deduce what could be concluded in logic B (say, Fregean logic) from a set of premises, and vice versa.

Comment: (cont.) You suggest that my comment "animal behavior" should be replaced by "Human behaviour", but in a bunch of earlier comments you did suggest that your One True Logic was deeply rooted in evolution and used other animal species to justify that, are you now suggesting there may be aspects fo the One True Logic that have only evolved very recently in the human lineage, or perhaps aren't fixed by inherited features of our brain at all?

Comment: @Hypnosifl "*multiple logical frameworks*" Mathematicians are free to call "logic" anything they like but that doesn't make is logic. It is mathematics, no doubt, but whether it is logic is an empirical question. The same applies to geometry for example. Whether mathematical geometry is really geometry is an empirical question. Not that mathematicians need to care, but the fact remains. Mathematical results are mathematical but not necessarily true of anything. Euclid's geometry is a good approximation for everyday business but not for black holes. Mathematical logic is toy logic.

Comment: @Hypnosifl 1. "*different logics can be equivalent*" Different mathematical systems may give the same results but what good is that if the results are false? 2. "*evolution*"This is the only plausible origin for logic but not essential to understand how logic works. 3. "*only evolved very recently*" Logic is probably a property of neurons and so presumably much older than humans and so the same for pigs and cows as for humans, but humans also have a capacity for articulated language and this is what opened the way to formal logic. 4. "*aren't fixed*" So why don't you reject the modus ponens?

Comment: *Different mathematical systems may give the same results but what good is that if the results are false?* "False" in what sense? As far as I can see a pure mathematical statement can only be "false" if it doesn't follow from the axioms and rules of inference in that domain of math. Of course, claims of applications to reality may be false (for example if it's assumed that two rays of light that are locally parallel will never cross based on Euclidean geometry, this can be false if space is actually non-Euclidean).

Comment: *Logic is probably a property of neurons and so presumably much older than humans* I think animals have evolved to make some sort of statistical inferences, but I don't see any evidence for purely "logical deductions" separate from that. for example if they always see a B whenever they see an A, but don't always see an A when they see a B, you don't need to assume they have some natural version of A->B, you can just assume some intuitive version of different conditional probabilities P(A|B) and P(B|A). I think a being needs language for deductions the being feels absolutely certain of.

Comment: *So why don't you reject the modus ponens?* Because modus ponens is generally either one of the axioms/rules of inference of any formal logic, or it's just taken as a *definition* of what we mean by "implies" or "if-then" in more informal discussions of logic. But I do reject the idea that there is any evolved pre-linguistic version of "logical implication" that is non-probabilistic, see above.

Comment: Speakpigeon, it's meanings that matter. What do you mean by "Santa Claus has a white beard"? If you mean "The actual person Santa Claus has a white beard," then you are assuming Santa Claus's existence. If you mean "The fictional Santa Claus is depicted as having a white beard," then you are not assuming Santa Claus's existence. But if you assume Santa's existence, your *meaning* is that Santa Claus exists and has a white beard, which is false, because Santa Claus doesn't exist.

Comment: About the use of the material conditional: Personally, I prefer to model the conditional "if p, then q" presuppositionally: presuppose the truth of p and ask whether or not q follows from p (in some sense of "follows," which may differ in specific cases). But I don't mind the use of the material conditional in arguments, because no conditional having a false antecedent can be used to derive any conclusion that couldn't already have been derived without it. When p is false, assigning "if p, then q" the truth-value "true" is harmless to derivations and leaves validity and soundness unaffected.

Comment: I meant to include that the presuppositional conditional simply has no truth-value when its antecedent is false, because to use it, one presupposes the antecedent's truth.

Comment: I will note that if Godel's incompleteness theorem is correct, then for any formal system, there are underivable proofs--and therefore also underivable falsehoods. "False" doesn't simply mean "underivable."

Comment: @MindWalk 1. I agree about the distinction between real Santa and a fictional Santa. 2. "*if you assume Santa's existence, your meaning is that Santa Claus exists and has a white beard, which is false, because Santa Claus doesn't exist.*" No, if you say "Santa Claus has a white beard" your meaning is clearly not "Santa exists and he has a white beard", whether you believe or not that Santa Claus exists. This is something Russell made up to make reality fits his model of it.

Comment: @MindWalk "*because no conditional having a false antecedent can be used to derive any conclusion*" The material conditional leads to deeming true false statements. These have been dubbed "paradoxes of the material implication", but this, too, is clearly fallacious.

Comment: @MindWalk "*Godel's incompleteness theorem*" Gödel "*proved*" his theorem using the material conditional and so, as Irving Clarence Lewis would have said, his proof proved nothing.